# python program to find out start & end time of every word in a audio file

Tags: python-3.x

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
framerate = 100
with sr.AudioFile("transcript.wav") as source:

    audio = r.record(source)

    decoder = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, show_all=False)

    print ([(seg.word, seg.start_frame/framerate)for seg in 
decoder.seg()])
```

I got the following error :

> File "C:/Users/KUMAR/Downloads/untitled2.py", line 11, in 
>       print ([(seg.word, seg.start_frame/framerate)for seg in decoder.seg()])
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seg'

How to fix that?

Comment: well I forgot to do formatting as I am new I will learn gradualy, any idea  to fix this problem @user404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, thanks for pointing me to the speech_recognition library. I didn't know it existed and I may have a use for it.

I see you have `show_all=False` but the [docs](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst) say that to get a `Decoder` object it needs to be True, so instead it is just returning the transcription as a string.

Here's the excerpt

> Returns the most likely transcription if show_all is false (the
>   default). Otherwise, returns the Sphinx
>   pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx.Decoder object resulting from the
>   recognition.

Comment: Ooops thanks for providing your valuable feedback & if u think my question helps you then vote up for my question it will boost my confidence..

Comment: @DeepakKumarSingh No problem. The question was clear. Likewise please check this as answered it it solved the problem!

Comment: hey as i am using CMU_sphinx and it does not support Hindi as a language & the output generated by it is rubbish on english language. Also Sphinx is creating its own type of object not as dict or str.

Comment: I need a solution that can give the start time and end time of every word & also the silence time between every word (preferably in Hindi language)

Comment: @DeepakKumarSingh You should post a new question. This topic was about the error. Now that the error is gone it is appropriate to make a new post with updated code.

Comment: i have been struggling with this implementation, if you finally resolve it, do you mind sharing @DeepakKumarSingh